# Making FEST to wait for the application to load

Tags: java, gui-testing, fest

I am new to FEST based GUI Testing.

MyFrame is the root class for my application.

```
 @Before    
      public void onSetUp() {

        MyFrame frame = GuiActionRunner.execute(new GuiQuery<MyFrame>() {
            protected MyFrame executeInEDT() {
              return new MyFrame();  
            }
        });

        frame2 = new FrameFixture(robot(), frame);

        frame2.show(); // shows the frame to test
      }
```

When I run the test case,

```
@Test public void testGui()
      {
          String rs = frame2.label("hl").text().toString();
                  assertTrue(rs.equals("First")); 
      }
```

The above method doesn't print the actual string present in the label.

I think the FEST API is not waiting for the application to load.

Is there any methods available to postpone the GUI element lookup ?

Comment: Look my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957334/making-fests-component-lookup-mechanism-wait-for-a-component-to-exist/11738497#11738497

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use the pause method from org.fest.swing.timing.

Have a look here http://fest.easytesting.org/swing/apidocs/org/fest/swing/timing/Pause.html

Answer (score 4):

```
//do your clicks
fixture.robot.waitForIdle();//give the GUI time to update
//do your asserts
```

this will pause your Code until your GUI has nothing left to update. The advantage to `Pause` is, that you do not have to wait longer than you need by passing a to large time interval.